# iOS5 -> iPhone App -> Google Maps not working anymore

Tags: iphone, google-maps, ios5, mkmapview

I developed an application with a Google Maps integration. Everything was okay, since I update to iOS5 with my iPhone 3GS.
My Google Maps implementation (MKMapView) shows me now

- a light blue page with map view
- the text no images with a grey background with satellite view
- a black page with a hybrid view

So what can be wrong?

Best Regards Tim

Comment: Can you show us some code? I am using MKMapView in several apps without any problems in iOS 5 and iPhone 3GS.

Comment: I really do nothing special, but also in the iOS5 simulator, I get the same result. I think anyone also had this problem and have an idea. It is difficult to put all code in here, because there is much stuff of loading and showing / updating annotations. But I see that some other people has this problem, but I can not found a solution.

Comment: I found the problem... my GPS goes wrong and I am landing in the sea, so it is blue, or black or "no images", because there are no images in this detail view.

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in my comment:
"I found the problem... my GPS goes wrong and I am landing in the sea, so it is blue, or black or "no images", because there are no images in this detail view."